# Strange black border on iPad/iPhone

Tags: html, iphone, css, ipad

I have a problem tough to debug, because I don't have any ios device and in simulator everything looks ok, but my cliect see something like that

http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/8587/vpej.png

Of course on other system the border don't appear. CSS for this

```
.item-small {
    height: 320px;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
.item-small .subdiv {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I've tried (like suggested in other solutions) to add

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">`

but with no result, any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of HTML element is this? A link? An image? Did you try to set `border: 0;` explicitly? Did you also try `outline: 0;`?

Comment: This is absolute container (for masonry) with elements in it (image, link, text etc). I added your suggested fixes but still have a border. Border have main container sizes so it probably causes the problem